# Как в react js реализовать сортировку карточек, которые "лайкнули"

Tags: reactjs

Всем доброго утра) Моя задача заключается в том,что бы вывести  на экран карточки-данные в массиве. Сделать,чтобы они "лайкались" и при нажатие на определенную кнопку отображались только "залайканые" карточки.

### Что я сделал

Я создал функцию  `const handleLike=()=> {setLiked(!liked);}`,которая меняет состояние и тем самым я добавляю модификатор `liked` к классу `place-card__like-icon`. Так же я передаю состояние liked классу place-card. Делаю это для того, чтобы при нажатие на кнопку `<button onClick={displayAdd} ></button>` я получил все "залайканые" карточки.

### Что то пошло не так

Вместо того, чтобы "лайкалась" одна карточка- "лайкаются" все. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

````
function App() {

const [liked, setLiked] = React.useState(false);
const [isDisplay, setDisplay] = React.useState(false);

const displayAdd=()=>setDisplay(!isDisplay);
const handleLike=()=> {setLiked(!liked);}





const comments = [{ 
   id: 1,
   author: 'Лиза',
   text: 'Все уже сдали деньги на субботник?',
 }, { 
   id: 2,
   author: 'Джеймс',
   text: 'Никто не видел мой сэндвич?',
 }, { 
   id: 3,
   author: 'Грег',
   text: 'Продам мопед',
 }]; 


return (
   <> 
   
   {comments.map((message, i) => (
     
     <div key={message.id} className={`place-card ${'liked' ? isDisplay &&  'display-none':''}`}>
   
     <div className="place-card__image" >
     <button onClick={displayAdd} ></button>
       <button className="place-card__delete-icon"></button></div>
       <div className="place-card__description">
         <h3 className="place-card__name">{message.author}</h3>
         <button onClick={handleLike} className={`place-card__like-icon ${liked && 'place-card__like-icon_liked'}`} ></button></div></div>

   ))}
         
   
   
   </>
 );
 }

export default App;```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант №1**

У вас сейчас одно состояние для всех карточек, потому что и `state` для них один.

Я предлагаю хранить свойство `liked` для каждой карточки внутри массива `comments`. И поместить этот массив в `state`

```
const [comments, setComments] = useState([{ 
   id: 1,
   author: 'Лиза',
   text: 'Все уже сдали деньги на субботник?',
   liked: false,
 }, { 
   id: 2,
   author: 'Джеймс',
   text: 'Никто не видел мой сэндвич?',
   liked: false,
 }, { 
   id: 3,
   author: 'Грег',
   text: 'Продам мопед',
   liked: false,
 }]);
```

Передаем функции `handleLike` явно `id` сообщения которое будем изменять. Вашу кнопку с `handleLike` переписываем следующим образом:

```
<button onClick={() => handleLike(message.id)} className={`place-card__like-icon ${liked && 'place-card__like-icon_liked'}`} ></button></div></div>
```

Пишем функцию `handleLike` с изменениями

```
const handleLike = id => {
    setComments(state => state.map(el => {
       if (el.id === id) {
           return {
               ...el, 
               liked: !el.liked,
           }
       }
       return el;
    }))
}
```

После этих изменений все должно работать

**Вариант №2**

Разделить компоненту с выводом массива (где у вас `comments.map`) и саму карточку.

Тогда для каждой карточки можно будет держать состояние и его менять. Но я бы не советовал такой вариант.

Comment: Илья Паймушкин,Большое спасибо за ответ!) Очень помогло.  Я немного поправил это выражение <button onClick={() => handleLike(message.id)} className={`place-card__like-icon ${message.liked && 'place-card__like-icon_liked'}`} ></button></div></div>и все заработало.

Comment: @Pavel отлично:) отметьте как принятый ответ пожалуйста:)